# What types of non-permanent GoPro mounts exist for the ceiling of a Cessna 172?

Tags: flight-training

What alternatives are available to using a permanent mount to place a GoPro on the inside ceiling center of a Cessna 172?

Comment: [Related](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/22141/8730)

Comment: Many aviators use [**RAM mounts**](http://www.amazon.com/RAM-B-166---GOP1U-Suction-Diameter-Adapter/dp/B0091RA0KS/), which have all sorts of different mounts for different devices, and different attachpoints like suction cups, clamps, and screw-on attachments.

Comment: RAM mounts are awesome - if you aren't worried about damaging the aircraft, there are a lot of different clamp and screwdown options as abelenky said.

Comment: Thanks all.  I need something that's not permanent since the aircraft belongs to my flight school.  Ideally something that can provide a view from the middle of the two front seats forward.  I wish I could use the GoPro adhesives on the ceiling but unfortunately they don't come off easily...I'll look at RAM mounts.

Answer (score 0):

I do tests on truck aerodynamics, and occasionally we put tufts on the vehicles. We then film these tufts to see how the flow behaves. We also use these RAM mounts, but sometimes one of them would come undone due to unproper mounting, dirt or flexing of the surface.

We solved this issue by adding redundancy in the form of the Rollei 3x Suction Cup Kit:
[image]

Disclaimer: Not affiliated to Rollei, this is just the first one we found.